# How to properly use Rtmv2 and RtmAddRouteToDest

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to modify the routing table with the Microsoft API. As far as I understood searching in internet, this one should be a good interface to use
[Using Routing Table Manager Version 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382335(v=vs.85).aspx)

I tried to follow the sample code in the section "Add and Update Routes Using RtmAddRouteToDest" and "Register with the Routing Table Manager", but nothing happens. My code run till the end without errors, but my routing table does not change.

I could not find help in Google regarding my problem. Someone can give me some hint? Or another sample code? Otherwise, do you have other Microsoft interfaces to suggest?

Thanks everyone

Comment: I have the same issue? Have you found the answer?

Comment: Hi @Boris, I did not found the answer, but actually I moved on and I didn't look over it in the last year. I am using the old interface, you can have a look at [MIB_IPFORWARDROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ipmib/ns-ipmib-_mib_ipforwardrow) and [CreateIpForwardEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-createipforwardentry). Unfortunately this solution works only for IPv4, so I will have the same problem when I will need to move to IPv6. If you have some suggestion for IPv6, tell me please :)

Comment: Thanks I am trying to look at XORP which is using this api